# World Bank via Pandas - looking up country regions

Tags: api, worldbank, python

I am getting country [data from World Bank](http://data.worldbank.org/) via [Pandas Remote Data API](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html).

Is there a way to get metadata for each country? In particular:

- Is it a country, or a region/group (e.g. `Arab World` or `Upper Middle Income`)?
- If it is a country, to which region does it belong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the metadata directly from this URL (xml returned by default):

```
http://api.worldbank.org/countries
```

It looks like it has what you need. Regions/groups are treated like countries but you can distinguish them based on empty or "NA" field values.

Comment: Great! I see that I can do it for JSON as well: http://api.worldbank.org/countries?format=json ([World Bank API Overview](http://data.worldbank.org/developers/api-overview) and [Basic Call Structure](http://data.worldbank.org/node/11)).